# MVC Pattern in Games: Animation?

Tags: c++, animation, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Let's say my game has entities, and let's say all of those entities have a collision-hitbox consisting of multiple shapes. Let's also assume skeletal animation is used and each collision-shape corresponds to one bone.
I implemented the basic MVC pattern by having one data-container, renderer and controller for each Entity type, fE:

```
class MyEntity:public Entity{
    public: int x, y, state; vector<hitbox> hitboxArray;

class MyEntityRenderer:public Renderer{
    void render(){
        ...
    }
}
class MyEntityController:public Controller {
    update(){}
    inputstuff(){}
}
```

How can I now actually implement animations, if I want the hitboxes translations be modified depending on the animation and it's progress?

If I only had an animation I would clearly put the whole stuff in the Renderer, but what now? How can I apply MVC to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animations are simply visual renderings of your model. You could have your entity enter a "jumping" state which will manipulate its y variable for its hitbox in the model. When you render the model, if your entity is in the jump state display its jump animation or image.

You do not want to manipulate your hitboxes based on the animation but manipulate your animation based on the hitboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems logical. Does it mean, that the animation of bones basically IS logic, and the rendering part really only renders "static" textures dependant on the location of the hitboxes/bones?  I guess so?